# DirectoryInfo object not released

Tags: c#, dispose, directoryinfo

I'm creating a application that loops through directories in a directory writes them to the console using the following code:

```
public void checkDirectory(string directory)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Checking... " + directory);

    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
    try
    {

        foreach (DirectoryInfo d in di.EnumerateDirectories())
        {
            checkDirectory(d.FullName);
        }

    }
    catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        cantAccessCount++;
        unableToAccess.AppendLine("Cannot access directory " + directory);
    }
}
```

The code loops through all of the directories and outputs the directory to the console as expected, but when I run it on a network path "\myserver\myfolder" if I go to and view my open files on "myserver" it shows the directory and all of it sub-directories as open files. Is there anyway to make sure these are closed when they are finished with?

Comment: @mason `checkDirectory` is the name of the method this code is in

Comment: @mason It's a recursive method

Comment: The code in the question is checkDirectory, it calls itself for each sub-directory it finds

Comment: I'd assume either the `DirectoryInfo` object or `EnumerateDirectories` will be opening the directory. You could try using `Directory.GetDirectories`. I'm adding as a comment because I am not entirely sure this will work.

Comment: I suppose this is possible, it does rather depend on the implementation of the file server and what kind of anti-malware product is installed.  What actually goes wrong?  If nothing then just ignore.  If you do have a concrete problem that makes your program fail then you must document it.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm afraid the result is the same

Comment: @HansPassant Nothing actually goes wrong, and I'm happy to ignore it, but my boss is less happy to. I think the worry is that if another program tries to do anything with the folders they will find them locked by my program.

Comment: @Ryan I will definitely look into it some more next week. I couldn't confirm what you're experiencing in my dev environment (yet), but I am very interested in this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is happening due to the recursive call. There is an overloaded version of EnumerateDirectories which accepts a SearchOption parameter. It enables you to walk through all subdirectories:

```
foreach (DirectoryInfo d in di.EnumerateDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    Console.WriteLine(d.FullName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested some code i wrote a while ago and it didnt show any open directories (or files) for me on a server just the open session itself, you could test it:

```
class Program
{
    static ConcurrentQueue<string> dirQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dirQueue.Enqueue(@"\\SomePC\SomeFolder");
        fetch();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void fetch()
    {
        string currentDirectory;

        do
        {
            if (dirQueue.TryDequeue(out currentDirectory))
            {
                try
                {
                    IEnumerable<string> newDirectories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(currentDirectory, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                    Array.ForEach(newDirectories.ToArray(), dirQueue.Enqueue);

                    Console.WriteLine("{1}", currentDirectory);
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        } while (!dirQueue.IsEmpty);
    }
}
```

This is just a fast copy I hacked together, the original is a threaded version so you might need to change some things.

Comment: I'm still getting the open files I'm afraid